# Reference Request: Resolution of singularities on surfaces in positive characteristic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity

I was wondering if anyone would have a good set of notes/references explaining the minimal resolution of ordinary singularities on algebraic surfaces in both characteristic zero and positive characteristic?

Comment: I believe resolution of singularities on a surface in positive characteristic was constructed in [Local Uniformization on Algebraic Surfaces Over Ground Fields of Characteristic $p \neq 0$](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F1970014) by Abhyankar. This paper is from the 1950s, so you may be able to find a more modern account if you look at works that cite this paper.